# How to set docker env file that inside the image

Tags: docker

i am a totally docker newb, so sorry for that

i have stand-alone docker image (some node app),
that i want to run in different environments.

i want to set up the env file with `run RUN --env-file <path>`
How ever, i want to use the env files that inside the image (so i can use different files per env),
and not on server.
so  would be the path inside image.

is there any way to do so? 
perhaps like "cp" (`docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:<path>`)
but doesn't seem to work.

what the best practice here?
am i making sense?
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you looking for the COPY / ADD command? https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Nope, my images already have "envfiles" folder with some env files,
i want to set the "docker run --env-file <path>" with internal path

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem to be a valid use case for the --env-file switch. The docs don't say anything about using it for stuff within the container, so my *guess* is that this is not possible. How many environment variables do you define within the files? If they are only a few, you can pass them with the -e option to your container. If you still want to do it within, you could write a small setter-script on startup, which reads the file defined via the -e switch.

Answer (score 1):

Docker bind mounts are a fairly effective way to inject configuration files like this into a running container.  I would not try to describe every possible configuration in your built image; instead, let that be configuration that's pushed in from the host.

Pick some single specific file to hold the configuration.  For the sake of argument, let's say it's `/usr/src/app/env`.  Set up your application however it's built to read that file at startup time.  Either make sure the application can still start up if the file is missing, or build your image with some file there with reasonable default settings.

Now when you run your container, it will always read settings from that known file; but, you can specify a host file that will be there:

```
docker run -v $PWD/env.development:/usr/src/app/env myimage
```

Now you can locally have an `env.development` that specifies extended logging and a local database, and an `env.production` with minimal logging and pointing at your production database.  If you set up a third environment (say a shared test database with some known data in it) you can just run the container with this new configuration, without rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the command to run docker

docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
Example
docker run --name test -it debian

**focus on following switch**

```
  --env , -e        Set environment variables
  --env-file  You can pass environment variables to your containers with the -e flag.
```

An example from a startup script:

```
sudo docker run -d -t -i -e REDIS_NAMESPACE='staging' \ 
-e POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_PASSWORD='foo' \
-e POSTGRES_ENV_POSTGRES_USER='bar' \
-e POSTGRES_ENV_DB_NAME='mysite_staging' \
-e POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR='docker-db-1.hidden.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' \
-e SITE_URL='staging.mysite.com' \
-p 80:80 \
--link redis:redis \  
--name container_name dockerhub_id/image_name
```

In case, you have many environment variables and especially if they're meant to be secret, you can use an [env-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file):

```
$ docker run --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash
```

> The --env-file flag takes a filename as an argument and expects each
>   line to be in the VAR=VAL format, mimicking the argument passed to
>   --env. Comment lines need only be prefixed with #